# smarty.get no longer working

Tags: php, smarty

I have some old php code that has been working happily.  I need to do some updating and have moved the code to another machine.  Everything is fine except this smarty code no longer works.

```
{$smarty.get.myvar}
```

I know it must be to do with differnt config settings but i can't figure it out. Register_Globals is off on both installations.

Comment: Did you try to create a template with single line `{$smarty.get.myvar}` and add append '?myvar=test_value' to URL?

Comment: I think the version of Smarty can matter. Especially, if $HTTP_GET_VARS is turned off.

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the "global" variables is here http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.variables.smarty.php

Make sure you have `request_vars_order` and `request_use_auto_globals` configured to your needs, but the syntax `$smarty.get.myvar` is completely fine.

Make sure the case is correct and you are not sending `$smarty.get.myVar`...

Answer (score 2):

This is a BAD way of working with request variables. Template should never fetch the variables directly from GPC vars. Variables should be validated by script, sanitized and then ->assigned to a template.

Comment: I know that, but until I have a moment to remove the use of smarty.get I need to make sure it works.  +1 for warning others off making the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this option:

```
{$smarty.get['myvar']}
```

I had this issue, and with this syntax it works